# H.264 Real-time Streaming, Timestamp in NAL Units?

Tags: android, flash, streaming, real-time, h.264

I'm trying to build a system that live-streams video and audio captured by android phones. Video and auido are captured on the android side using MediaRecorder, and then pushed directly to a server written in python. Clients should access this live feed using their browser, so the I implemented the streaming part of the system using flash. Right now both video and audio content appear on the client side, but the problem is that they are out of sync. I'm sure this is caused by wrong timestamp values in flash (currently I increment ts by 60ms for a frame of video, but clearly this value should be variable).

The audio is encoded into amr on the android phone, so I know exactly each frame of amr is 20ms. However, this is not the case with video, which is encoded into H.264. To synchronized them together, I would have to know exactly how many millisecs each frame of H.264 lasts, so that I can timestamp them later when delivering content using flash. My question is is this kind of information available in NAL units of H.264? I tried to find the answer in H.264 standard, but the information there is just overwhelming.

Can someone please point me at the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Richard, I am struggling with the same thing. Have you figured out what to do here?

Answer (score 2):

Timestamps are not in NAL units, but are typically part of [RTP](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550&rct=j&q=RTP%20rfc%20tools&ei=mwrJTdipHIjasgbghNGpAw&usg=AFQjCNFuaAdrvbsWzLlfjUePlFbcuTTGvw&cad=rja). RTP/RTCP also takes care of media synchronisation.

The [RTP payload format for H.264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984) might also be of interest to you.

If you are not using RTP, are you just sending raw data units over the network?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I'm sending raw NAL units over the network. I figured each frame of video has duration of about 60ms, so I increment timestamp in flash by 60ms each time a frame is sent. (It seems like one NAL unit corresponds to one frame of picture).  I'll definitely check out RTP, but I wonder how exactly will synchronization be taken care of?

Comment: I think perhaps in your case that your presentation times of the video are not exactly 60ms apart. I have not worked on Android: does your capture device (MediaRecorder) provide you with timestamps?

Comment: You're right, the presentation times are not exactly 60ms apart. It's not a fixed value, but varies between 59 and 60. While doing real-time streaming, there is no information available about timestamps. Can RTP accomplish sync without this information?

Comment: o..kay, I guess I'm really unlucky... is there any other information that I can use in NAL units? Like how long a frame should remain on the screen before it's replaced by the next frame? Also, can raw h.264 be played back?

Comment: Not as far as I know, what about using the time at which the frame is captured? Also, what sort of sync issues are you experiencing: is it a constant offset or does it get worse the longer you play?